# Custom sequence generator for Hibernate 5

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, grails, hibernate-5.x

I want to create a custom sequence generator in Hibernate 5 to create a sequence per table in Postgresql. Using Hibernate 4 I did the following in my dialect:

```
/**
 * Get the native identifier generator class.
 *
 * @return TableNameSequenceGenerator.
 */
@Override
Class<?> getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass() {
    TableNameSequenceGenerator
}

/**
 * Creates a sequence per table instead of the default behavior of one sequence.
 * From <a href='http://www.hibernate.org/296.html'>http://www.hibernate.org/296.html</a>
 */
static class TableNameSequenceGenerator extends SequenceGenerator {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * If the parameters do not contain a {@link SequenceGenerator#SEQUENCE} name, we
     * assign one based on the table name.
     */
    @Override
    void configure(final Type type, final Properties params, final Dialect dialect) {

        Boolean sequencePerTable = Holders.config.getProperty(SEQUENCE_PER_TABLE, Boolean, true)

        if (sequencePerTable) {
            if (!params.getProperty(SEQUENCE)) {
                String tableName = params.getProperty(TABLE)
                String schemaName = params.getProperty('schemaName')
                if (schemaName) {
                    params.setProperty(SCHEMA, schemaName)
                }
                if (tableName) {
                    params.setProperty(SEQUENCE, "seq_${tableName}")
                }
            }
        }
        super.configure(type, params, dialect)
    }
}
```

You can see the full code here: https://github.com/kaleidos/grails-postgresql-extensions/blob/master/src/main/groovy/net/kaleidos/hibernate/PostgresqlExtensionsDialect.groovy#L53

I'm trying to migrate to Hibernate 5 but I don't know how to configure the previous behavior. I've modified the code to extends from `SequenceStyleGenerator` because now `SequenceGenerator` has been deprecated but my code is never executed. I think this has to do with the fact that the method `getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass` has also been deprecated.

I've been looking for a way to create a custom sequence but all examples I've found are focused on annotate my domain class with the sequence generator. What I'm looking for is a way to define all the sequences in a global way.

Comment: `spring.jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings: true` config is required in `application.yml` in order to use `SequenceStyleGenerator`

Comment: On a side note, `getNativeIdentifierGeneratorClass()` can be replace by `getNativeIdentifierGeneratorStrategy()` which return a `String`

Comment: `use-new-id-generator-mappings` might not work in a Grails app because that is specific to spring data jpa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Graeme noted (https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/10234) the default name of the sequence has changed in Hibernate 5, so adding

`id generator: 'sequence', params: [sequence_name: 'book_seq']`

to the mapping block does the trick. The problem is that it's necessary to add that to **every** domain class.

I'm still looking for a way to define that setting globally, maybe setting `prefer_sequence_per_entity` to true for every entity.

**UPDATE:** Finally we found a workaround to define a sequence per table globally. Just add the following to the file `application.groovy`:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    id generator: 'org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator', params: [prefer_sequence_per_entity: true]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Ivan! I tried only this configuration, which worked too.

```
 grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
      id  params: [prefer_sequence_per_entity: true]
 }
```